# Determining the optimum resistance in an LED light?

Tags: led, resistors, hobbyist

I'm reassembling an old rechargable torch which originally used a 4.2V lead acid battery. I changed it to a 3.7 li-ion battery and it's working just fine.

The lighting plate contains 9 LEDs (connected in parallel) with a 3.6 ohm resistor (color code: orange,blue,gold,gold) on the power supply.

Can I can lower the resistance a bit to get better brightness since there is a drop in the supply voltage now?

If yes, how do I calculate that value?

It might sound unnecessary since the voltage drop is really small, but I'm more interested in the method of approaching such problems.

Comment: While maybe you can, I dont suggest doing so here. If the resistor is connected in series with the LED, then it is easy. But the resistor could be doing one of many other functions. I dont suggest you do this because the 4.2V of the lead acid is its maximum, but the 3.7V of the Li-Ion battery is the nominal. While fully charged, the Li-ion battery will have a voltage of 4.2V, so changing that resistor may damage something while the battery is fully charged.

Comment: @AnasMalas  Point noted

Comment: lead acid has a much smaller voltage swing across its capacity range than does lithium, so you may find that a simple resistor gives you unacceptable brightness variation from max to min charge, and you might prefer a current source. OTOH, the low light output at low battery voltage may be useful as a fallback long lasting 'get you home' light, also warning that you are at your battery's low voltage limit, which must not be gone below, or you will damage them.

Comment: @Neil_UK on a second note , I'm trying to learn python these days. Do you have suggestions

Comment: @blackSmith How is that related at all to this question? But as I happens, I am a pythonista, well, wannanbe pythonista, not too good, still learning, so maybe a better teacher than somebody who knows it all. Suggestion - find an application, start coding in python, check the libraries, there are gazillions of them. If you're stuck for a problem, try project Euler. If you want some direct help, then leave some contact details.

Comment: @Neil_UK iout of curiosity I looked at your profile and I really don't want to spam this site with irrelevant interests. But coincidence does happen. I'll definitely share my contact details soon.

Comment: @blackSmith Well, if you are stalking me, you can take the opportunity to check on my few python Q/As on the main stackOverflow and codeReview, and see whether my coding domain aligns with yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I can lower the resistance a bit to get better brightness since
> there is a drop in the supply voltage now?

Yes you can drop the resistance one problem you'll have is you also need a Battery Management System (BMS) so the li-ion cell does not drop below its under voltage

> If yes, how to calculate that value?

Without having the a I-V curve for the diode it won't be easy to calculate the drop across the diode. If you had a bench power supply with a constant current function you could find the IV curve. The way to do that would be to plug the supply in across only the diodes and then start at a low current like 1 milliamp and then increase the current all the way up to something like 100 milliamps all the way charting both the voltage and the current. You could then size the [resistor](https://eepower.com/resistor-guide/resistor-applications/resistor-for-led/).

Another way to do it would be to reduce the resistor size by very minor increments. Like try a 3.5 ohm resistor and measure the current then try a 3.4 ohm. One problem is you can't go too low or you can burn out the LEDs so be careful

Comment: Sorry to ask, what's full form of BMS?

Comment: @blackSmith battery management system. To be honest, given that a white LED won't work below about 3V, you could live without one. Or use protected cells.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't need to change the resistor at all.

Your lithium cell will output from a high of 4.2 V, down to perhaps 3 V before it's damaged.

The lead acid cell would output 4.4 to 4.5 V on charge, spending most of its time at about 4 V, before being deemed to be fully discharged at about 3.66 V.

Ideally your lithium cell should be a protected cell, or else use an external protection circuit to prevent its full discharge. If you use a simple resistor in series however, then the LED will take little current as the supply drops to 3 V. This will a) warn you that the battery approaching its lowest safe voltage b) provide a low discharge current so this low light will last a long time (at a backup 'get you home' level)